# How to get Pose matrix from matched points of Open SURF

Tags: objective-c, ios, computer-vision, 3d, augmented-reality

I want to use open SURF for recognition in AR in iPhone.After matching the source and destination images,I don't know how to get pose matrix from matched points of source image and destination image in camera frames.Like this blog http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/02/markerless-augmented-reality-on-iphone/#comment-993   But he has not explained this point.Please any tutorial, code or book so that I could get the concept.  Please guide me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(^.^)"Hi sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"

Hi @Rehman I'm working with AR right now and I'm using one open source his name is Aurasma [aurasma](http://www.aurasma.com/) is very easy you don`t have to create an additional line of code just create one UIButton and launch the AR viewController is very easy to use. Take a look

Comment: Thanks NTTake, I spent few hours on googling to get the source of Aurasma but couldn't. Actually I need help on "How to find Projection and ModelView Matrices of an image in camera frame" so that after recognition I could pass these matrices to open GL ES to draw some 3D model exactly registered with the image in camera frame to get Augmented Reality